# What do these diamond and slash note heads mean?

Tags: piano, jazz, lead-sheets

[image: measure from jazz piano lead sheet]

Can someone tell me what do the symbols here mean? and how to play them in triplets as written in the lead sheet?

Comment: I’d just like to add to the answers that when using rhythmic notation like this a diagonal line indicates an unspecified pitch of a quarter note or less and a diamond is used for a half note or more.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - often there's just 4 slashes (in 4/4) which doesn't tell much - except 1-2-3-4 - comp. as you wish. But with more complex rhythm patterns, there will be tails where quavers and shorter notes are needed, and rests are written the same as in standard staves.

Answer (score 7):

This is rhythmic notation; it indicates the rhythm to be played, but not the literal notes to play. The notes played would be from a Gm7 chord, indicated above the staves, voiced according to the tastes of the pianist.

The rhythm itself is as given in @Tim's answer.

Answer (score 4):

A bracket with a 3 above it means play the 3 bracketed notes in the time it would take to play two of that same value note. So here, there's a minim - 2 beats, and then the triplet - consisting of a quaver rest and a crotchet - both of which constitute *one beat*. Followed by the final crotchet, making the total of 4 beats.

Now, that triplet - how to play? I'd probably count 12 for that bar, to start with. That means the minim gets 6 counts, no.7 is the rest, 8,9,10,11,and 12 are the tied notes at the end. In counting 12, emphasise **1** **4** **7** and **10**, as they are still where the normal 1 2 3 and 4 are. So, put simply - 1st note plays on 1, other note plays on 8.